# Put request using Net :: HTTP returns status 200 but does not work correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, net-http

I created a method to change a subscription on an online platform through the API made available. The request returns status 200, but the change does not appear on the platform.

The method is as follows:

```
  def self.update_subscription_item_value(subscription_id, item_id, value)   

    url = URI("https://api.iugu.com/v1/subscriptions/#{subscription_id}")

    http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
    http.use_ssl = true
    request = Net::HTTP::Put.new(url)
    request['authorization'] = 'Basic ' + Base64.encode64(Iugu.api_key + ':').chomp
    request.body = "{\"subitems\":[{\"id\":\"#{item_id}\",\"quantity\":\"#{value}\"}]}"

    response = http.request(request)
    puts response.read_body
  end
```

request return: Net::HTTPOK 200 OK readbody=true

does anyone know why I didn't get any changes to the platform?

Comment: If you get a 200 back, it should be fine. According to the [API docs](https://dev.iugu.com/reference), there are two environments: TEST and LIVE. Make sure that you're sending your request to the one you're watching for changes.

Comment: Hello Stefan,

I already checked that the request is being made for the correct environment. In addition, it is worth mentioning that exactly the same request works correctly in the postman. But when executed via the ruby ​​console it does not make any changes to the platform model